# OrderAddView is missing a QuerySet. Python Django

Tags: python, django

Почему такая ошибка?

*OrderAddView is missing a QuerySet. Define OrderAddView.model, OrderAddView.queryset, or override OrderAddView.get_queryset().*

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<str:tag>', OrderAddView.as_view(), name='order_add'),
]
```

**view**

```
class OrderAddView(CreateView):
    from_class = FastOrdersForm
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tag'] = self.kwargs['tag']
        print('tag ', context['tag'])

        return context
```

**form**

```
class FastOrdersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device', 'serial', 'comment', 'status']
        widgets = {
            'device': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'serial': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 5}),
        }
```

Comment: у вас есть модель OrderAddView?

Comment: нет, я же ее на вызываю ни где или как?

Comment: model = Orders вот только ту модель вызываю, и она есть

Comment: хм... а не views.OrderAddView.as_view() должно быть в urlpatterns?

Comment: работало, все отлично было, я не знаю, что-то где-то поправил

Comment: работало без этого views.OrderAddView.as_view()